How to use Java agent intercept to instrument java.net.Socket with javaassist
I am working on a project where I need to write some header to the socket output stream right after the socket is connected.
I want to intercept at low level such as java.net.Socket and its connect function public void connect(SocketAddress endpoint, int timeout).
The transform function looks like below
    public static byte[] transform(final ClassLoader loader, final String className, final byte[] classFileBuffer) {
        loader.loadClass(...);

        final ClassPool classPool = ClassPool.getDefault();
        classPool.appendClassPath(new LoaderClassPath(loader));
        classPool.appendSystemPath();
        classPool.importPackage(...)

        final CtClass ctClass = classPool.makeClass(new ByteArrayInputStream(classFileBuffer));

        if (className.equals("java/net/Socket")) {
            final CtMethod method = ctClass.getDeclaredMethod("connect");
            final String s = "System.out.println(\"I am in Socket.connect!\");";
            method.insertAfter(s);
            return ctClass.toBytecode();
        }
        
        return classFileBuffer;
    }

I have confirmed that java.net.Socket.connect() is called but the byte code seems to never work. I tried having some dummy in the string appended and still no error.
Interesting thing is that below works for java.net.SocksSocketImpl. So I cannot figure out what is wrong.
Can I please get some help here?
Thanks!

First of all, this loader.loadClass(...); at the beginning is definitely wrong, regardless of what’s inside the (…). Further, doing all that work before checking className.equals("java/net/Socket") is very inefficient (a transformer might get called for every class). You should check the name first and immediately return null if you’re not interested in the class (you might return the classFileBuffer unaltered instead, but it’s easier for the caller to check for null than to compare the returned array with (a copy of) the original array).

Thanks @Holger for the suggestion. Now I return classFileBuffer if class it out of interest. The problem I got is caused by overloaded methods and resolved by checking parameters and whether the method is abstract or not.

I figured out the problem myself later. There are multiple connect overloading methods in java.net.Socket. In my code above I did not check the parameters and method body. So I got an abstract method with one parameter and no method body. Injecting byte code to method without body will lead to an error.
I ended up by adding check on parameter numbers and types plus body and succeeded in instrumenting the method.
